# When To Use A WCF Service Vs. An ASP.Net Page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm very new to web development; but I've created a webpage/game in Silverlight.  I'm now implementing some 'high score' functionality.

I think I understand the 'general' idea of WCF - I went through a 'Getting Started' tutorial and I've written a WCF Service that let's clients submit their score and request a List of the top 10 scores.

But, I guess what I'm struggling with is, when do you want a WCF service VS. a simple ASP.Net page that accepts POST data?  Is it as simple as use 'WCF when you aren't providing a UI - ASP.Net when you are?' or is it really a matter of what data you want to get back (It seems easier to work with return values in WCF).

I know this is very n0obish and general, but I would appreciate some direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A service is useful when you want to be client agnostic. In other words, you want someone to be able to submit scores via the web page, via a mobile app, or even from a third party application, written either for the web, Mac, Windows, etc.

You can also set up a service that the web application uses to submit, if you want that flexibility, so it is not completely either/or.